# Install OpenCV on Mac OS 10.5

Tags: macos, opencv, homebrew, osx-leopard

I want to install OpenCV 2.4.9 on Mac OS 10.5.8 with Intel Core Duo processor(32 bit) and only for C++(no Python required). Please help. I want the latest version of OpenCV because I want to use traincascade function provided in OpenCV which seems to have been upgraded in the latest version of OpenCV.

Answer (score 1):

I think easiest way is using `homebrew`. It is a package manager for OS X. You can install it from [here](http://brew.sh/).

After installing brew, you can easily install OpenCV just by running following command from console:

```
brew install opencv
```

**EDIT**

[Requirements](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Installation#requirements) for homebrew

Comment: Which version of OpenCV gets installed? I am also not able to download homebrew using the command given on that page.

Comment: It automatically installs the latest one, 2.4.9, or if you want you can install another version.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I installed using MacPorts.